# Mi comprobación de Colliders no funciona correctamente y no termino de ver por qué

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Este es un proyecto de unity, por ahora este script está colocado sobre un rectángulo vertical con un collider en su misma forma. En los margenes superior e inferior Hay dos coliders los cuales referencio correctamente en el script. Tengo el siguiente código para controlar el movimiendo, por ahora solo vertical, y que debería detenerse en cuanto toca el margen superior:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider2D ColSuperior;
    public Collider2D ColInferior;
    public Collider2D Self;
    public float VelMov = 0.3f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        if(Self.IsTouching(ColSuperior)==false)
        {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x ,transform.position.y + VelMov, transform.position.z);
        }
        else
        {
                print("COLISIONANDO");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código a priori no parece que exista fallo, quizá lo único, agrupar ese condicional en llaves por si acaso se pueda estar saltando el `else` al ser más de una linea de código.

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
     if(!Self.IsTouching(ColSuperior))
     {
       transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x 
                                        ,transform.position.y + VelMov, 
                                        transform.position.z);
     }
     else
     {
                print("COLISIONANDO");
     }
}
```

Por otro lado, para que exista colisión, Unity requiere del componente RigidBody, que le debes asignar a tu entidad que se mueve desde el editor. Asegúrate también de que la entidad tiene desactivado el ser Kinemático, ya que de esta forma las fuerzas o colisiones no afectan al RigidBody y puede que sea lo que te está produciendo el problema de que no lo detecte.

[image: Editor de Unity 2020.1.17f]

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, finlamente era todo lo que me dijiste y en el rigid body marcar use full kinematic colission, Después de marcar esa casilla con todo lo que has dicho ha funcionado, muchas gracias por la ayuda limpiando el código corrigiendo mi falta de conocimeinto

Comment: Me alegro! Si, es bueno coger buenas costumbres a la hora de codificar mientras se aprende. Yo soy estudiante universitario y aun tengo muchos gazapos pero se van corrigiendo poco a poco. Mucha suerte con el proyecto